# What would prevent me from copying pads (or other components) in Altium?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I'm attempting to copy and paste several components from one Altium PCB to another. I would like to copy and paste all the components all at once, because they are mounting hardware for another PCB, and their relative layout is crucial.

My problem is that when I select and copy all the components (a header, an outline, and 5 mounting holes/pads), only the outline and header are copied over, not the mounting holes. I've already unlocked all the components, thinking that might've been preventing it, but that didn't help. I've also already closed and rebooted Altium several times.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that you are selecting the header as a component, but you are instead selecting the pad of the hole instead of the component, therefore Altium is discarding those when copying them to the clipboard.

What you can do is make sure that you have the PCB inspector open, and start by selecting only one pad for each component you want to copy. Once you are done just click on the link to "Component" in the PCB Inspector window, and after that you can copy and paste into the new PCB file.

Comment: This did the trick! I was doing exactly what you said, selecting the "pad" instead of the "component". Once I switched over to the "component" inside the PCB inspector, I was able to then copy/paste it.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem if all components are "not locked". There also needs to be the same stackup (layers) between projects. I copy parts routinely between projects and I've never had a problem.

Try copying the components that will not copy one at a time (use the relative reference of copying to make sure they end up in the same place).

The easiest thing might be to copy the PCB file from one project to another and just use that to start with.

Comment: I attempted to copy them one at a time, but they just wouldn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't copy and paste, try "exploding" the part (make it free primitives). Then you should be able to copy and paste